# JavaScript API to work with Excel files stored on OneDrive?

Tags: javascript, excel, onedrive

I want to create an web application that uses an Excel file stored on the users OneDrive, preferably directly from JavaScript. The web application should not be running inside Excel on the client, so I think that excludes the [JavaScript API for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185(v=office.1501401).aspx).

Are there any alternative APIs or is it simply not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OneDrive Javascript SDK to get Excel files (download) from a user's OneDrive, and then manipulate that content once retrieved from the service.

You can use the [OneDrive Javascript SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243643.aspx) directly to traverse the file hierarchy and find an Excel file, or you can use the [Web picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659733.aspx) to let a user choose (or save) the file (free UI, no need to build hierarchy traversal).

In terms of actually manipulating the Excel file, there are certainly modules and libraries available to help do this (node.js, python)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a way to work directly with an spreadsheet through a REST api or similar, e.g. without downloading the entire spreadsheet. That would allow me to use it as a data store.

Comment: That sounds like something that Office Online would offer, if it exists. This came up with a cursory search: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Building-an-Office-Web-f98650d6

Comment: Jeanine, as far as I can see, the Office online stuff, which I also link to in my original question, requires you to run inside the Office applications or Office web applications. I would like to run in a completely separate web app, where I use an Excel spreadsheet as the data store for users personal data.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Then you would need to use a csv library. I'm only familiar with Python's offerings, but I'm sure nodejs would have something similar for Javascript. If you built a datastore using one of these libraries, and then saved it back to OneDrive, you would be able to get an embed link for the excel file if you would like to display it in your web app. However, putting app data in a user's OneDrive seems risky and possibly the wrong pattern, since they could alter it at any point destroying your semantics.